# Typescript - Array of extended Classes of specific Parent

Tags: typescript, types

I have an abstract class called `Action`:

```
abstract class Action { ... }
```

And I have several classes that extend `Action`:

```
class Vote extends Action { ... }
class Upload extends Action { ... }
...
```

How can I declare an array of classes that extends `Action` (but shouldn't accept `Action` itself?

```
const actions: (typeof Action)[] = [
  Vote,    // OK (passes)
  Upload,  // OK (passes)
  File,    // OK (fails)
  Action   // BAD (passes)
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a constructor signature that returns the abstract class instead of the abstract class. The abstract class does not have a constructor in the type system so it won't be valid but any derived class inheriting the abstract class will be valid.

```
abstract class Action { ... }

class Vote extends Action { ... }
class Upload extends Action { ... }

const actions: (new () => Action)[] = [
  Vote,    // OK (passes)
  Upload,  // OK (passes)
  File,    // OK (fails)
  Action   // Ok now (fails)
]
```